# django pagination and annotate

Tags: mysql, django

My investigation shows that using annotate which involves another table increases dramatically the sql query time.

there is no point to calculate this count on every page the user selects.

my question is how do I avoid calculating this count on every page?

would it be wise to use a model attribute to store this count?

what do you suggest?

Comment: Are you trying to get the number of objects on the current page? This would usually be the number of records per page, except for the last page

Comment: no, I'm trying to get the count on manyToMany field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding raw sql to improve the query.
this did the trick and now each pagination takes ~3 ms.